# still needing help w/ react function to display the value of subtracting two other variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i have asked a similiar question previously and it was not ansswered to where it helped me all the way.. .so here it goes;

code:
CartPortal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import OrderSummary from "./OrderSummary";
import ProductList from "./productList";
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { Subscribe } from 'unstated';
import CartContainer from './CartContainer';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    keys:["xs", "s", "md", 'lg', "xl"],
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 450,
      md: 768,
      lg: 1024,
      xl: 1920
    }
  }

});


class CartPortal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(); 
    const currentState = {
      priceToThreshold: null
    };
    const priceToThreshold = '';
    this.FreeShipping = '';
    this.props.priceToThreshold = '',
    this.freeShippingThreshold = 75;


  FreeShipping = function() {
    return <div className="box"><div className="shipment-box-free"><p className="shipping-cost">Awesome you got <span>Free Shipping</span></p></div></div>;
  }

  PaidShipping = function(props) {
    return <div className="box"><div className="shipment-box"><p className="shipping-cost">Add <span id="amount">$ ${cart.priceToThreshold.toFixed(2)}</span> more for Free Shipping!</p></div></div>;
  }

  priceToThreshold = function(props) {

  }

textToShowInComponent = (props) =>{
  if (this.props.priceToThreshold >= 0) {
     return FreeShipping();
      } 
      return PaidShipping(); 
      }

    }


  render() {
    return(
      <Subscribe to={[CartContainer]}>
      { cart =>(
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <div id="checkoutPortal">
            <div className="shipping-tracker">
              {this.textToShowInComponent()}
            </div>
            { cart.state.items.length == 0 ?
              (
                <Grid container 
                  justify="center"
                  alignItems="center"
                  spacing={0}>
                  <Grid id="emptyCart" item xs={12}>
                      <h1>Your Shopping Bag is Empty</h1>
                      <a href={cart.state.homeURL} className="actionLink">Continue Shopping</a>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              )
              :
              (
              <Grid container 
                    justify="center"
                    spacing={0}> 
                <Grid item md={8} xs={12}>
                  <ProductList></ProductList>
                </Grid>
                <Grid className="orderSummaryContainer" item md={4} xs={12}>
                  <OrderSummary></OrderSummary>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            )}

          </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      )}
      </Subscribe>
    )
  }
}

export default CartPortal;
```

what ineed to have happen is i need to conditionally render the Free Shipping or PaidShipping based off of the basePrice int he users cart. I am pulling the basePrice from CartContainer.js which is what this file subscribes to. so i need to display the difference from freeShippingThreshold: 75; from the basePrice (cost of cart) if this amount is greater than 0 then display the free shipping component, else display paid shipping. Additionally i need to calculate the difference from freeShippingThreshold - basePrice if this amount is less than 75 i need to find the balance between those numbers andoutput that as a variable in paidShipping. Can you guys help me out?

TY.